# An internal error occurred during: "Installing Software". The profile is currently in use

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-mars

When I am trying to install **E-git plugin** from the

> http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

in **Eclipse Mars.1 Release** (4.5.1) at **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

but its give me **error**:

> **An internal error occurred during: "Installing Software". The profile**
>   **is currently in use.

please suggest me appropriate answer for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I do Some steps in **eclipse** to resolve this problem.

> **Help>Install new software>Uncheck “Contact all update sites during
>   install to find required software”**

Simply disable   **“Contact all update sites during install to find required software”**